# how to generate a large dropdown in multiple rows fast way

Tags: performance, angularjs

On my page I have around 100+ rows, in each row I have to should dropdowns (dropdown containing 80 items). Now when I am generating the rows and generating the dropdown in each rows its damn slow using angularJS.

```
<div ng-repeat="row in Rows">
    <div class="mydd">
         <select ng-model="row.mappedList"
            ng-options="item.id as item.fieldName for item in myList" class="form-control">
    </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Rows > 100 and myList items > 80

I dont want bindings on my select box, so whats the best way here to get the rendering fast?

Comment: Where does the list come from? Can you break it up in to smaller chunks and paginate it on the fly (as they scroll down, or ask for the next set or whatever you want)?

Comment: Nope... pagination is not the option here. Can we just not copy a static select element from somewhere on page and paste in this location for each row?

Comment: To be honest, if this is really a must-have it sounds like something that would be better handled with custom jQuery (for the drawing). It's very hard to picture a usable UI with 100 rows and a drop down of 80 items for each row.

Comment: did some tests,it's not that bad.You might want to clean up your models so they contain only the strictly minimum relevant data  : http://plnkr.co/edit/4sURdGQHm7VjXUMeX1ax?p=preview